# Scala 12.x and Java 11 `String.lines`, how to force the implicit conversion in a chained call?

Tags: java, string, scala, java-11

**Problem description**
Scala StringOps provides a `lines` method that returns an `Iterator[String]`.
Java 11 added `lines()` with return type `java.Stream[String]`.

In a chained method call like

```
val text: String
text.lines.foldLeft("")(_ + _)
```

the code will no longer compile and throw an exeption that `foldLeft` is not defined on java.Stream[String].
As far as I understand the implicit resolution is no longer applied as the lines method now is already found in java.String.

How can I express that I want the implicit to be applied (the one without parens) isntead of the java.String.lines()

**Additional info**

- I found `linesIterator` but it is deprecated.
- Downgrading is an option but is there a way around it.
- `val text : StringOps` looks realy ugly but solved it but I am unhappy with this solution

Comment: What about using `Stream#reduce`?

Comment: Also, I think you can do `(text: StringOps).lines.foldLeft(...)`

Comment: Nice catch, thx :) `(text: StringOps)` with the parents doesn't braek the chain.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The conflict between `StringOps#lines` and jdk11 `java.lang.String#lines` is a bug in scala, see issue [11125](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11125).

The fix for this bug is to un-deprecate `linesIterator`, which was done in 2.12.7.

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.7 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11).

scala> "a".lines
res0: java.util.stream.Stream[String] = java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@2df259d0

scala> "a".linesIterator
res1: Iterator[String] = <iterator>
```

Comment: The intermediate solution then is to use `Predef.augmentString(` until this is fixed in 2.13 ?

Comment: Yes, `Predef.augmentString("")` seems to be the less ugly solution for now.

Comment: I wish I could give you more upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

You can force Scala to use the implicit conversion to `StringOps`, which will use the old `lines` method:

```
(text: StringOps).lines.foldLeft("")(_ + _)
```

Comment: This and inserting `augmentString` are equivalent, can't think of a strong reason to prefer one or the other. ( But note that `StringOps` is in `scala.collection.immutable` and isn't imported by default.)